# I am not able to display Images using Picasso ImageLoader

Tags: android, picasso

I am working on recyclerview and cardview to load some images using Picasso Library. 
I am pasting my code here.

This is my DivineDestinationDistricWiseActivity.

```
public class DivineDestinationsDistrictWise extends Fragment {
RecyclerView all_divine_dest_places_list;
List<Places> placesList;
GridLayoutManager glm;


public DivineDestinationsDistrictWise() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_divine_destinations_district_wise, container, false);

   all_divine_dest_places_list = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.all_divine_places_rv_id);
    glm = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity() , 2);
    all_divine_dest_places_list.setLayoutManager(glm);
    all_divine_dest_places_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
    intializeData();
    initializeAdapter();
    return rootView;
}

private void intializeData() {
    placesList = new ArrayList<>();
    placesList.add(new Places("Divine Destinations", R.drawable.hyd_balakampeta_ellamma));
    placesList.add(new Places("Adventure Journeys", R.drawable.hyd_birla_mandir));
    placesList.add(new Places("boatings", R.drawable.hyd_jagannatha_temple));
    placesList.add(new Places("Heritage Spots", R.drawable.hyd_mecca_masjid));
    placesList.add(new Places("Shopping", R.drawable.hyd_peddamma_temple));
    placesList.add(new Places("Nature Discovery", R.drawable.hyd_peddamma_temple));
    placesList.add(new Places("Wild Life", R.drawable.wild_life_main));

}
private void initializeAdapter()
{
    DDDWAdapter adapter =new DDDWAdapter(placesList);
    //  places_type_list_recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(this));
    all_divine_dest_places_list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

This is my adapter class.

```
public class DDDWAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DDDWAdapter.DivineDestViewHolder>  {
CardView cv;
Context context;



public class DivineDestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView personName;
    ImageView photo_city;



    public DivineDestViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv=(CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_places_id);
        personName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.places_list_id_tv);
        photo_city=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_places_list_id);
        context = itemView.getContext();
        photo_city.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}

List<Places> place;
DDDWAdapter(List<Places> place)
{

    this.place=place;
}


@Override
public DivineDestViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.places_type_list, parent, false);
    DivineDestViewHolder pvh = new DivineDestViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DivineDestViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.personName.setText(place.get(position).city_name);
    holder.photo_city.setImageResource(place.get(position).photo);

    //here i am trying to load images with Picasso Library but not getting Images.
Picasso.with(context).load(R.id.image_places_list_id).into(holder.photo_city);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return place.size();
}
```

}

This is my Places class.

```
  public class Places {
String city_name;
int photo;

Places(String city_name, int photo)
{
    this.city_name = city_name;
    this.photo=photo;
}

}
```

I have tried by inserting like below if I use like this I am getting images. But When I scroll the screen Images are scrolling with little jerky behaviour.

```
 Picasso.with(context).load(place.get(position).photo).into(holder.photo_city);
```

Please help me out from this...  Thanks in advance.....

Comment: image is in your resource folder so that your apk size is big so android os not allocated memory for your application this resign problem is come try to get from network like URL

Comment: @Naveen Thanks for your reply.. Isn't there any alternate way to do... without getting it from network URL..

Answer (score 0):

first generate the setter getter of the Places Class

```
public class Places  {
String city_name;
int photo;

public SampleClass(String city_name, int photo) {
    this.city_name = city_name;
    this.photo = photo;
}

public String getCity_name() {
    return city_name;
}

public void setCity_name(String city_name) {
    this.city_name = city_name;
}

public int getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}

public void setPhoto(int photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}
}
```

and then initialize your adapter and send also a context to it like

```
DDDWAdapter adapter =new DDDWAdapter(getActivity,placesList);
```

and then your adapter look like this

```
public class DDDWAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DDDWAdapter.DivineDestViewHolder>  {
CardView cv;
Context context;
List<Places> place;



public class DivineDestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
View.OnClickListener{
TextView personName;
ImageView photo_city;



public DivineDestViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    cv=(CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_places_id);
    personName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.places_list_id_tv);
    photo_city=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_places_list_id);
    context = itemView.getContext();
    photo_city.setOnClickListener(this);


}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
}


DDDWAdapter(Context context,List<Places> place)
{


this.context=context;
    this.place=place;

}


@Override
public DivineDestViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.places_type_list, parent, false);
DivineDestViewHolder pvh = new DivineDestViewHolder(v);
return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DivineDestViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.personName.setText(place.get(position).city_name());


//here i am trying to load images with Picasso Library but not getting Images.

Picasso.with(context).load(place.get(position).getPhoto()).into(holder.photo_city);


}

@Override

public int getItemCount() {
    return place.size();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried as you said but when I scroll down the screen Images are scrolling with jerky behaviour. Can you please suggest how to make it smooth scrolling instead of jerky.

Comment: please put less size(dimention images) for smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting image resource directly to your imageView and then latter you are assigning  **R.id** instead of **R.drawble** to load via Picasso

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DivineDestViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.personName.setText(place.get(position).city_name);
    holder.photo_city.setImageResource(place.get(position).photo);

    //here i am trying to load images with Picasso Library but not getting Images.
Picasso.with(context).load(R.id.image_places_list_id).into(holder.photo_city);

}
```

You need to load images like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DivineDestViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.personName.setText(place.get(position).city_name);

    //here is how you should be loading image
   Picasso.with(context).load(place.get(position).photo).into(holder.photo_city);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I tried like this also but Images are scrolling with jerky behaviour only. Is there any other way to make the image scroll smoothly...